# Bootstrap styles being applied before my own style sheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

the use of `!important` is exceptionally bad so I attempt to avoid it as best I can, When I downloaded Bootstrap 3.0, I placed the call to the `.css` file **AFTER** my core style sheet is called. Thus any modifications I make to elements like `.h1, h1{}` should render before Bootstraps is called.

How ever that is not the case. Bootstrap, in chrome, is applying its styles and crossing mine out. Only by applying `!important` doe it work - this is wrong how ever.

Any ideas how to get around this aside from `!important`? I cannot just modify the `bootstrap.css` because that's wrong too - other parts of the site use bootstrap as is, while some parts change some functionality.

Comment: Place your CSS after Bootstrap's.  This is Cascading in action :)

Comment: put your css after bootstraps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your core style sheet needs to be called **AFTER** bootstrap.css.  CSS loads from top to bottom there fore the last rule it loads takes presidents over other rules.

Comment: Understood I assumed it had to be called BEFORE

Comment: @LogicLooking if this solves your issue please check the checkmark.